# How to handle with Google Cookies window in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I can not find a way to handle with the Google Cookies window at the first navigation to google.com. I would like accept the cookies but I can not scroll down on the page.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjPhV.png)

I guess focus is staying on the main page which is google.com but I could not switch to the cookies window. I have tried the iframe swithc, alert or popup iterator. None of them did not work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: is it ok if i post python code? cause i'm not familiar with java

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
String chromedriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("L2AGLb")).click();
```